# What is the proper way to write a BIOS Parameter Block? (Bootloader)

Tags: x86, boot, bootloader, bios

After writing some basic code for a bootloader, I made an `.img` image to test it. On Bochs, it ran just as expected; however, when I wrote the image to a USB and tried to test it on a real device, I suddenly got a `No bootable device found` message. After a bit of web crawling on the internet, I found out that I may need a BIOS Parameter Block (BPB). I copied and pasted a BPB that I found, and suddenly *everything worked.* Here is the code, in case it is needed:

```
bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:        DB 2
bpbRootEntries:         DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:        DW 2880
bpbMedia:               DB 0xF0
bpbSectorsPerFAT:       DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:       DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:               DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "AOS Floppy "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "
```

From my understanding, the BPB describes the physical properties of a storage device. I also understand the individual components of the BPB. However, I do not see how a single BPB could describe the many file systems that the bootloader can be loaded from.

That is, wouldn't some of these values change depending on the device that the end-user decided to use for installing and running the operating system? Does the BPB describe the volume that the bootloader is found on? And if so, would these properties also not vary depending on the user's device?

Comment: One possibility is that you are booting your USB with USB Floppy emulation (I'd check the BIOS settings). I've known some systems that use USB with Floppy Emulation (not Hard disk emulation) to require a BPB.

Some BIOSes are known to load the boot sector, attempt to detect if a BPB exists (often checks for the first instruction in the bootloader being a `JMP` instruction), and then proceed to modify the BPB after it is loaded into memory to reflect the drive geometry.

Comment: It would indeed make sense if the BIOS modified the BPB to reflect the drive (I believe I have read this somewhere as well), but like you said, only some BIOSes do so.