# Boot sector works only in QEMU

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, boot, bootloader

I have this boot sector:

```
mov ah, 0x0e ; tty mode
mov al, 'H'
int 0x10
mov al, 'e'
int 0x10
mov al, 'l'
int 0x10
int 0x10
mov al, 'o'
int 0x10

jmp $ ; jump to current address = infinite loop

; padding and magic number
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I compiled it with:
`nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin`

And I ran it with `qemu-system-x86_64 ./boot.bin`

It worked fine, but when I flashed it on USB with `etcher boot.bin`, it didn't boot on my computer. My architecture is x86_64.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Chances are you need a BPB. Can't find the duplicate, in the meantime here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36297690/547981). EDIT: Here is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144059/547981). See if that helps. If yes, I will close this question.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time.